# Google Cloud VM Machine: Cuda out Memory

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pytorch

I have recently set-up an account on Google Cloud VM Machine, and I am using the Nvidia Tesla K-80GPU.
When I run my Pytorch code I am getting the following error:
[image]

But when I run the same code on Google Colab, it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very detailed issue description on [Github](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/16417) about this problem. Is your Colab environment of the same size regarding available Memory? I would recommend (one of) the following code changes, that reduces the amount of data kept in memory:

- Reduce the batch size in your notebook.
- Reduce input dimension size in your notebook.

Comment: Since this looks CUDA ran out of memory, making the batches smaller as we can read on this answer may be a good way. 

Also you could try to give 1 more GPU to the VM. 

As I can see in this document: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus (Control+f for "K80"):

12 GB of GPU memory corresponds to 1 GPU count of K80, maybe you should try 2GPUs on your VM, perhaps your workloads require more resources.